# React Native release build crash issue, but on debug it is working fine

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am facing the release build crash issue on iOS and getting the below error:

```
[error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation
2020-12-31 01:16:15.086 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation
2020-12-31 01:16:15.125896+0530 EPG[11841:95064] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation, stack:
<unknown>@1064:17089
v@2:1474
<unknown>@1063:426
v@2:1474
<unknown>@1062:340
v@2:1474
<unknown>@1055:6339
v@2:1474
<unknown>@1054:156
v@2:1474
<unknown>@1053:229
v@2:1474
<unknown>@1051:167
v@2:1474
<unknown>@847:284
v@2:1474
<unknown>@846:211
v@2:1474
<unknown>@442:454
v@2:1474
<unknown>@413:400
v@2:1474
<unknown>@412:138
v@2:1474
<unknown>@6:61
v@2:1474
d@2:876
global code@1935:4
'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108b0e6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fb779b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   EPG                                 0x000000010a3f6f05 RCTFormatError + 0
    3   EPG                                 0x000000010a46c11c -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 508
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108b7dec __invoking___ + 140
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108b4fd1 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 321
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001108b52a4 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 68
    7   EPG                                 0x000000010a42ab0a -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 578
    8   EPG                                 0x000000010a42cd94 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 246
    9   EPG                                 0x000000010a42cb1c ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 78
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001139daf11 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001139dbe8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001139e26fd _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 788
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001139e328f _dispatch_lane_invoke + 422
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001139eeb65 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 719
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff52301a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff52300b77 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Do any one has idea that what might cause and issue like this, i am having the version of react-native as "react-native": "^0.61.2" and my package. json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.0.8",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "1.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "6.7.1",
    "base64url": "3.0.1",
    "i18n-js": "3.5.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "native-base": "2.13.12",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.2",
    "react-native-camera": "3.21.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "1.5.2",
    "react-native-color-picker": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-config": "0.12.0",
    "react-native-dash": "0.0.11",
    "react-native-document-picker": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "0.2.2",
    "react-native-geocoding": "0.4.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "1.3.4",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "3.7.0",
    "react-native-open-maps": "0.3.5",
    "react-native-pdf": "6.1.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-print": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-ratings": "6.5.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.13",
    "react-native-share": "3.1.2",
    "react-native-ssl-pinning": "1.4.5",
    "react-native-tag-input": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-webview": "7.6.0",
    "react-redux": "7.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.12.0",
    "rn-secure-storage": "2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I already tried it by uninstalling the node_modules and doing the pod install many times, but not having getting it fixed with any solution.

Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, do you solve it?

Comment: I am still facing the same issue not resolved it

Comment: I solve this yesterday, try looking in your code for something like
`@babel/types`
for me, it was to remove
`import { identifier } from '@babel/types';`

Answer (score 16):

**I solve this yesterday, try looking in your code for something like @babel/types for me, it was to remove import { identifier } from '@babel/types'; – aharon vishinsky**

Thank you aharon vishinsky -- it is very helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you are save my life.

Comment: @AnsalAntony I'm facing the same problem but in which file did you delete this import?

Comment: @JoppeMeijers I was searched the "@babel/types" key in the whole project and I was founded this import in the dashborad.js file

Comment: For me it was in svgIcons.js file

Comment: i don't have this import in all of my files

Comment: @abdelhedihlel Remove (import { *** } from '@babel/types'). Maybe not Identifier.

Answer (score 5):

For my case:
The vscode plugin "Auto import" seem insert a "import" statement:

```js
import { OBJECTMEMBER_TYPES } from '@babel/types';
```

So, just delete it, then you should be ok.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem and would never have guessed this was the source of the problem this whole time. I thought it was my Expo SDK, or my Node version... damn.it was the auto import.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this, been at this for days.
In my case, looks like VSCode added this at some point.

```
import { placeholder } from "@babel/types";
```

Most likely when I added the [placeholder for TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#placeholder). Deleting this line fixed the issue.